# Non continuity of a functional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, continuity

I work on the set $E$ of real valued polynomial. I define on the set the norm $\lVert P\rVert = \sup_{i}\lvert a_i\rvert$ where $P=\sum_{i=0}^{q}a_i X^{i}$. I studied the functional given by $\phi(P) = P(1)$. I saw that this functional is not continuous but my reasoning leads me to think the opposite.

So I would like to express my reasoning here in order to have your feedback on what it’s wrong in my reasoning.

First I thought about sequential continuity so I decided to consider a $P\in E$ and a sequence $(P_n)$ in $E$ converging to $P$. $P$ is defined as above and $P_n = \sum_{i=0}^{d}a_i^{n}X^{i}$

I noticed two things : the degree of the sequence $(P_n)$ should be equal or greater than the one of $P$ and each $a_i^n$ should converge to $a_i$ for $i\in \{ 0,1,…, q\}$ and goes to $0$ if $i>q$. Using this I get

$$
lim_{n\to\infty}\phi(P_n) = lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=0}^{d}a_i^{n} = \sum_{i=0}^{d}a_i = \phi(P) 
$$

Which is clearly false in fact since it can be shown that this functional is not continuous for $P = \sum_{i=0}^{q} X^{i}$

I would like to have your help to understand what is false in my reasoning please. Thank you a lot !

Comment: The degree $d$ may  depend on $n$. So $P_n$ should be of the form $\sum_{i=0}^{d_n}a_i^nX^i.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thank you for your comment ! I think I see : nothing prevents the terms of the sequence to have different degrees as long as the coefficients outside the range of the degree of $P$ gets smaller and smaller as $n$ increases ? And since this condition does not imply the convergence of $d_n$ to $d$ what I wrote is wrong !

Comment: Yes. For example $P_n=\sum_{i=0}^n{1\over \sqrt{n+1}}X^i$ tends to $0,$ but $P_n(1)=\sqrt{n+1}$ does not tend to $0.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Very clear. Thank you a lot !